# The 'npm outdated -g' current is not the same as my 'npm -v'

Tags: sharepoint-online, npm

My `npm -v` is 6.13.4 but my current in `npm outdated -g` is 6.11.3. How would I remedy that issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the location of the current npm: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm. I replaced it with https://github.com/npm/cli and now there is no imbalance when I run `npm outdated -g`